# Heroku Project with node express and mongoLAB

Tags: node.js, rest, heroku, express, mlab

How do you connect and create the rest api from node express to work with mongolab on heroku ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way to connect to MongoLab from a Node.js app running on Heroku is to use the Node.js MongoDB driver:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/node.JS#node.JS-Node.jsDriver